# Which data type should i use to store Google Adwords code in database

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am building a back end system which allow user to enter Google Adwords code from the back end. Which data type should i set my Google Adwords column to in my database? I tried with 'text' data type but it does not recognize the symbol "<" & ">" in ... Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Text datatype in a database doesn't care about any "special symbols" like that, or treat them any differently to "special symbols" like "M", or "a" or "r" or "k".... you're simply not displaying them correctly in a web browser (which does treat them differently).... use "view source"

Comment: Use VarBinary DataType

Comment: Yes, TEXT is perfectly suited. The problem is somewhere else. Probably a character encoding problem. For instance: you encode, but you do not decode.

Comment: <label for="google_adw">Google Adwords</label>

<input type="text" name="google_adw" id="title" required autofocus maxlength="255" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $results['article']->google_adw )?>" />

This is how i coded inside my backend

Comment: you can use varchar (255)